# shell script declare associative variables from array

Tags: bash, shell, variables, sh

I have array key-value pairs separated by space,

```
array=Name:"John" ID:"3234" Designation:"Engineer" Age:"32" Phone:"+123 456 789"
```

Now I want convert above array as associative variables like below,

```
declare -A newmap
newmap[Name]="John"
newmap[ID]="3234"
newmap[Designation]="Engineer"
newmap[Age]="32"
newmap[Phone]="+123 456 789"

echo ${newmap[Name]}
echo ${newmap[ID]}
echo ${newmap[Designation]}
echo ${newmap[Age]}
echo ${newmap[Phone]}
```

I'm able to get value for given key using file,

```
declare -A arr
while IFS='=' read -r k v; do
   arr[$k]=$v;
done < "file.txt"
echo "${arr[name]}"
```

But I want to implement same functionality using array instead of file.

Comment: your `array=Name:...` is not a valid array definition so we need a better description of how the data is currently stored; if `array` really is an array, what does `typeset -p array` generate?  what code have  you tried so far (please update the question with the code you've tried so far)?  also, what do you mean by `Array might be in varied size`?

Comment: I updated the question and I mentioned about array length

Comment: Still `array` is NOT an array. it is just a (broken) variable assignment, How do you define/create an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A version without `eval`:

```
array='Name:"John" ID:"3234" Designation:"Engineer" Age:"32" Phone:"+123 456 789"'
declare -A "newmap=($(perl -pe 's/(\w+):"/[\1]="/g' <<< "$array"))"
echo ${newmap[Phone]}
# output : +123 456 789
```

Comment: Indeed `eval` is not required. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a sed to reformat input data before calling `declare -A`:

```
s='array=Name:"John" ID:"3234" Designation:"Engineer" Age:"32" Phone:"+123 456 789"'

declare -A "newmap=(
$(sed -E 's/" ([[:alpha:]])/" [\1/g; s/:"/]="/g' <<< "[${s#*=}")
)"
```

Then check output:

```
declare -p newmap
```

```
declare -A newmap=([ID]="3234" [Designation]="Engineer" [Age]="32" [Phone]="+123 456 789" [Name]="John" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Working with the **variable** `array` that's been defined as follows:

```
$ array='Name:"John" ID:"3234"   Designation:"Engineer"  Age:"32"   Phone:"+123 456 789"'
```

**NOTES**:

- assuming no white space between the attribute, ':' and value
- assuming there may be variable amount of white space between attribute/value pairs
- assuming all values are wrapped in a pair of double quotes

And assuming the desire is to parse this string and store in an array named `newmap` ...

We can use `sed` to break our string into separate lines as such:

```
$ sed 's/" /"\n/g;s/:/ /g' <<< ${array}
Name "John"
ID "3234"
  Designation "Engineer"
 Age "32"
  Phone "+123 456 789"
```

We can then feed this to a `while` loop to populate our array:

```
$ unset newmap
$ typeset -A newmap

$ while read -r k v
do
    newmap[${k}]=${v//\"}         # strip off the double quote wrapper
done < <(sed 's/" /"\n/g;s/:/ /g' <<< ${array})

$ typeset -p newmap
declare -A newmap=([ID]="3234" [Name]="John" [Phone]="+123 456 789" [Age]="32" [Designation]="Engineer" )
```

And applying the proposed (and slightly modified) `echo` statements:

```
$ (
echo "Name        - ${newmap[Name]}"
echo "ID          - ${newmap[ID]}"
echo "Designation - ${newmap[Designation]}"
echo "Age         - ${newmap[Age]}"
echo "Phone       - ${newmap[Phone]}"
)
Name        - John
ID          - 3234
Designation - Engineer
Age         - 32
Phone       - +123 456 789
```